# Openweather api call failure in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to fetch weather data via open weather api. I noticed in console that the data is not downloading even though the connection to the api was also made correctly. By entering the API address in the browser, the data will be displayed. After clicking the get weather button, no data is downloaded. I came across a problematic snippet in my code. What causes the problem in this code?

```
 e.preventDefault();

    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
```

This piece of code above causes problems when fetching data through the API. If I delete it the data via API downloads without any problems and I get the current weather in London.

Entire App.js

```
import React from "react";

import './App.css';

import 'weather-icons/css/weather-icons.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Weather from "./components/weather.component";
import Form from "./components/form.component";


const API_KEY = "79b5009058dfaeaae8ed70533cb72a0d";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      city: undefined,
      country: undefined,
      icon: undefined,
      main: undefined,
      celsius: undefined,
      temp_max: undefined,
      temp_min: undefined,
      description: '"',
      error: false
    };

    this.weatherIcon = {
      Thunderstorm: "wi-thunderstorm",
      Drizzle: "wi-sleet",
      Rain: "wi-storm-showers",
      Snow: "wi-snow",
      Atmosphere: "wi-fog",
      Clear: "wi-day-sunny",
      Clouds: "wi-day-fog"
    };
  }

  calCelsius(temp) {
    let cell = Math.floor(temp - 273.15);
    return cell;
  }

  get_WeatherIcon(icons, rangeId){
    switch(true){
      case rangeId >= 200 && rangeId <= 232: 
        this.setState({icon: this.weatherIcon.Thunderstorm})
        break;
      case rangeId >= 300 && rangeId <= 321: 
        this.setState({icon: this.weatherIcon.Drizzle})
        break;
      case rangeId >= 500 && rangeId <= 531: 
        this.setState({icon: this.weatherIcon.Rain})
        break;
      case rangeId >= 600 && rangeId <= 622: 
        this.setState({icon: this.weatherIcon.Snow})
        break;
      case rangeId >= 701 && rangeId <= 781: 
        this.setState({icon: this.weatherIcon.Snow})
        break;
      case rangeId === 800: 
        this.setState({icon: this.weatherIcon.Clear})
        break;
      case rangeId >= 801 && rangeId <= 804: 
        this.setState({icon: this.weatherIcon.Clouds})
        break;
      default: 
        this.setState({icon: this.weatherIcon.Clouds})
    }
  }

  getWeather = async(e)=>{

    e.preventDefault();

    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;

    if(city && country) {
      const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=${API_KEY}`);
  
      const response = await api_call.json();
  
      console.log(response);
  
    this.setState({
      city: response.name,
      country: response.country,
      celsius: this.calCelsius(response.main.temp),
      temp_max: this.calCelsius(response.main.temp_max),
      temp_min: this.calCelsius(response.main.temp_min),
      description: response.weather[0].description,
    });
      this.get_WeatherIcon(this.weatherIcon, response.weather[0].id);
    } else {
      this.setState({error: true});
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Form loadweather={this.getWeather} error={this.state.error}/>
      <Weather 
        city={this.state.city} 
        country={this.state.country} 
        temp_celsius={this.state.celsius}
        temp_max={this.state.temp_max}
        temp_min={this.state.temp_min}
        description={this.state.description}
        weatherIcon={this.state.icon} 
      />
    </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

form.component.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./form.style.css";

const Form = props => {
    return(
    <div className="container">
        <div>{props.error ? error() : null}</div>
        <form action="">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-3 offset-md-2">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        name="city" 
                        autoComplete="off" 
                        placeholder="City"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        name="country" 
                        autoComplete="off" 
                        placeholder="Country"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3 mt-md-0 text-md-left">
                    <button onSubmit={props.loadweather} className="btn btn-warning">Get Weather</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    );
}

function error() {
    return(
    <div className="alert alert-danger mx-5" role="alert">
        Please Enter City and Country
    </div>
    )
}
export default Form;
```

weather.component.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const Weather = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="cards pt-4">
            <h1>{props.city}</h1>
            <h5 className="py-4">
               <i className={`wi ${props.weatherIcon} display-1`} /> 
            </h5>

            {props.temp_celcius ? (<h1 className="py-2"></h1>): null}
            <h1 className="py-2">{props.temp_celsius}&deg;</h1>

             {minmaxTemp(props.temp_min, props.temp_max)}

             <h4 className="py-3">{props.description}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

function minmaxTemp(min,max) {
    if(min && max) {
        return(
            <div>
                <span className="px-4">{min}&deg;</span>
                <span className="px-4">{max}&deg;</span>
            </div>          
        );
    }
}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: Try this.. <Form loadweather={(e) => this.getWeather(e)} error={this.state.error}/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in **form.component.jsx**

Try using

```
<input className="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Get Weather" />
```

instead of

```
<button onSubmit={props.loadweather} className="btn btn-warning">Get Weather</button>
```

Also, use

```
<form onSubmit={props.loadweather}>
```

Refer to this just in case:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Happy coding!